# Importing complex numpy arrays

Tags: import, complex, dataset

Related question: [Formatting Imported Complex Arrays from Python (csv. files)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240418/formatting-imported-complex-arrays-from-python-csv-files)

I am trying to import a large numpy array to Mathematica but the strategy in the question above is far too slow. For a 100-by-100 array it already takes quite a long time. Is there a fast, elegant way to import a complex numpy array?

Here is some code to generate such an array in python:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random

myArray = np.zeros((1000,1000),dtype='complex')
for (i,k) in enumerate(myArray):
    myArray[i] = numpy.random.normal(0,1,1000)+1J*numpy.random.normal(0,1,1000)

np.savetxt("exampleArray",myArray)
```

Comment: Can you, please, specify your version number? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could export binary reals from Python and [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) [`"Real64"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Real64.html).

Convert Python's `numpy.ndarray` `myArray` of complex numbers into reals of their real and imaginary parts and export binary with.

```
myArray.view(float).tofile("exampleArrayBinary")
```

Then `Import` with

```
r = Import[
   FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "exampleArrayBinary"}]
   , "Real64"
   ];
```

The import should hold $1000 \times 1000 \times 2 = 2000000$ items

```
Dimensions@r
```

> ```
> {2000000}
> ```

[`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) into pairs and [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) [`Complex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complex.html)

```
r = Complex @@@ Partition[r, 2];
r[[1]]
```

> ```
> 2.41713 +2.45023 I
> ```

The 100000 complex numbers are recovered.

`Import` `"Real64"` is instantaneous for this example.  However, you do lose the dimensions of the array.

An alternative would be to

1. find a Python library for a file type that that supports matrix exports and has support in Wolfram Language, like [`"MAT"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MAT.html).
2. Convert Python's array to reals and export the matrix
3. Import into Mathematica and partition & convert each row as above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I will accept your answer but also add my own because your strategy helped me come up with another that I think is also relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to export and then import that. Just use the [ExternalEvaluate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html) functionality or an ExternalLanguageCell (on mac: Shift + .):

[image]

```
exampleArray = ExternalEvaluate["Python", "import numpy as np
import numpy.random
myArray = np.zeros((1000,1000),dtype='complex')
for (i,k) in enumerate(myArray):
    myArray[i] = numpy.random.normal(0,1,1000)+1J*numpy.random.normal(0,1,1000)
myArray
"]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot set up `ExternalEvaluate` functionality on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using imports the data quickly but is fragile. What I did was export the data in Python as

```
myArray.astype(np.complex128).tofile("myData.dat")
```

then in Mathematica I used the symbol `BinaryReadList` passing the appropriate data type in order to read in the array.

Comment: Can you, please, note your version number for future users? This is very helpful as you state that you cannot use `ExternalEvaluate` and may serve as a workaround for future users in the same version as you.

Comment: When I posted the question I was on version 12.2, now I am on version 12.3. Using `ExternalEvaluate` is a bad call anyway.